# Javascript- I have created checkboxes in a javascript function need help linking them

Tags: javascript

I am just wondering if anyone can help me with regards to the method of making something happen **IF** a checkbox is checked and **THEN** a button is clicked?

I understand how to give buttons functions but I don't understand how to make the checkboxes value show when a button is pressed after the checkbox was selected.

I will add a little code snippet here - any advice would be really greatly appreciated!

**This is the javascript where I have created my checkbox input**

```
var caption = imgurl[i].getElementsByTagName('caption')[0].firstChild.data;

var checkBox = document.createElement("INPUT");
checkBox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
checkBox.setAttribute("value", caption);
div2.appendChild(checkBox);
```

When one of these checkboxs is selected and this button is pressed I want the checkboxes value to show in a div named "textspace"

**This is the html for the button**

```
<input type = "button" value = "Add item to Cart" id = "shoppingcart">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the checkbox input in the variable `checkBox`, use that to show its `checked` property by adding an event listener for `click` on your button.

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  result.innerText = checkBox.checked;
});
```

**Snippet:**

```js
var caption = 'Caption', 
    div = document.getElementById('chk'), 
    result = document.getElementById('result'), 
    btn = document.getElementById('shoppingcart')
;
var checkBox = document.createElement('INPUT');
checkBox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
checkBox.setAttribute('value', caption);
div.appendChild(checkBox);


btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  result.innerText = checkBox.checked;
});
```

```html
<div id="chk"></div>
<input type="button" value="Add item to Cart" id="shoppingcart">
<hr/>
<div id="result"></div>
```